# How to use two different sized images as input into a deep network?

Tags: deep-learning

I am trying to train a deep neural network which uses information from two separate images in order to get a final image output similar to [this](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7477589/). The difference is that my two input images don't have any spatial relation as they are completely different images with different amounts of information. How can I use a two-stream CNN or any other architecture using these kinds of input?

For reference: One image has size (5184x3456) and other has size (640x240).

Comment: Does scaling the images destroy the representation?

Comment: Can also try padding

Comment: Simply create two parallel networks and at some point collapse them into a single flow using (as the paper suggests) either feature concatenation or by applying some binary operator on the two. Your question is very broad to get a specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: It doesn't matter that you have two image. You have exactly the same problem when you have one image as input that single image can have different sizes.

There are multiple strategies to solve this problem:

- **Cropping and scaling**: Just force the input in the size you need it. The cropping is done to make sure the aspect ratio is correct. Sometimes the same image but different parts of it are then fed into the network and the results are combined (e.g. averaged).
- **Convolutions + Global pooling**: Convolutional layers don't care about the input size. At the point where you care about it, you can make [global pooling](https://keras.io/layers/pooling/#globalmaxpooling2d). This means you have a pooling region which will always cover the complete input, no matter of the size.
- **Special layers**: I don't remember the concept or name, but there are some layers which allow different sized input... maybe it was one of the attention-based approaches?

### Combining two inputs

Look for "merge layer" or "concatenation layer" in the framework of your choice:

- [Keras](https://keras.io/layers/merge/)

### See also

- Keras: [Variable-size image to convolutional layer](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1920)
- Caffe: [Allow images of different sizes as inputs](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/557)

Comment: spatial pyramid pooling after convolutions and before FC. check https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.4729